AWS Load Balancer returns a 502 error on the request. What did I do wrong?
I have configured my load balancer, target group and created an entry in Route 53.
The certificate is not expired, I received it today.
In the security group I opened ports 80 and 443 for everyone.
What did I do wrong, why am I getting a 502 error on requests to my server?


Hi and welcome to stack overflow. First, this question is not in scope for this forum (which is limited to development topics). Second, there is a lot of troubleshooting that you need to do. 502 means that something is wrong with the target instance. Is some web server running there successfully on port 9000? is security group set up correctly for ec2 (not for ELB)? Finally, you mention certificate which is not relevant and shows that you need some help in troubleshooting. If you don't have AWS support plan, try re:Post or somebody more experienced on the team. Good luck

Start by seeing whether your requests make it to the EC2 instance. Do you have logging in the app there? That will tell you whether the problem is in reaching the instance, or in how the instance responded to the request.
